# Issues With Center Aligning A Horizontal Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I've tried several things to move the nav bar over as a whole, but I'm stuck. The container for the nav bar needs get its size based on the size of the nav bar. The amount of links will be changing periodically so i can't used a fixed width.

Regardless of what i do in parent tags, the float: left in the css for li keeps it to the left. I've tried numerous things but i finally to decided to admit that im just in over my head.

Heres the css:

```
#main {
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#nav_bar {
    height: 72px;
    width: auto;
    text-align:center;
}


#main_nav { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline;}
#main_nav li { float:left;}
#main_nav li a { text-indent: -999999px; overflow: hidden; display: block; height: 72px; } 

#home { background: url(NavBar/home.jpg); width: 105px; }
#home:hover { background: url(NavBar/home.jpg); 0 0 !important; }

#main_nav:hover li a#home { background-position: -232px center; }


#logo { background: url(NavBar/logo.jpg); width: 116px; }
#logo:hover { background: url(NavBar/logo.jpg); 0 0 !important; }


#main_nav:hover li a#logo { background-position: -232px center; }


#photo { background: url(NavBar/photo.jpg); width: 116px; }
#photo:hover { background: url(NavBar/photo.jpg); 0 0 !important; }


#main_nav:hover li a#photo { background-position: -232px center; }


#animation { background: url(NavBar/animation.jpg); width: 116px; }
#animation:hover { background: url(NavBar/animation.jpg); 0 0 !important; }


#main_nav:hover li a#animation { background-position: -232px center; }


#print { background: url(NavBar/print.jpg); width: 116px; }
#print:hover { background: url(NavBar/print.jpg); 0 0 !important; }


#main_nav:hover li a#print { background-position: -232px center; }


#other { background: url(NavBar/other.jpg); width: 116px; }
#other:hover { background: url(NavBar/other.jpg); 0 0 !important; }


#main_nav:hover li a#other { background-position: -232px center; }
```

and heres the html:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="nav_bar">
<ul id="main_nav">
            <li><a href="" id="home">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="photo">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="print">Print</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="logo">Logos</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="animations">3D</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="other">Other</a></li>
        </ul> 
</div>
<div id="footer">Copyright</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: @user1931022 he's referring to a website which lets you run live HTML/CSS/JS. I've posted an answer using it to show you how I fixed it.

Comment: Usually, you can post your code at JSFiddle.net and hit save, then post the URL here for all of us to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/5PXEe/1/

This centers the `ul` and will expand nicely with new menu items

You needed `display: inline-block;` in your main_nav